# Structural templates in scholarly writing

Tags: academic-writing, structure, planning

I'm interested in the different ways that academic essays can be structured.  Of course there is the 5-paragraph style learned by most Americans in secondary school:

- Introduction
- Argument 1
- Argument 2
- Argument 3
- Conclusion

And there's this more advanced structure often taught in English 101 type courses in college:

- Introduction
- Background
- Argument
- Counterargument and Refutation
- Conclusion

What are some other ways to structure an academic paper?  Side question: I've read several popular (as opposed to scholarly) articles which lack an introduction and/or conclusion (more often the conclusion).  Is this ever acceptable in a scholarly work?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a scientific paper published in an academic journal the format is:

1. Abstract (summary of your topic and the results).
2. Introduction
3. Materials and Methods
4. Results
5. Discussion/Conclusions
6. Reference list.

Comment: For an empirical study, that is the correct structure. Here is a classic article by psychologist Daryl Bem that goes into more detail: http://dbem.ws/WritingArticle.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I've always written my History using 3x5 cards and reading what I think are the salient aspects from a Primary Source. My first work concerned the use of lead shot as a contributing factor in the decline of the North American duck population. (Seriously. I was 14 years old when I wrote it.) So I went to "the Library" and read all the articles arguing for and against said argument then established my thesis and wrote and footnoted accordingly.